# C - Delete the i-th Character from a Writable Char Array

Tags: c, string

Deleting the i-th character from a writable char array (the first index is 0, second is 1 and etc). Do you think this is a legitimate way to perform this task:

```
void delete_char(char *str, int i) {
    strcpy(str + i,str + i + 1);
}
```

Can we count on it that the function strcpy will always copy the characters from the leftmost to the rightmost positions ?

Comment: what do the docs for strcpy() say?  -> "If the strings overlap, the behavior is undefined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted code has undefined behaviour, from [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

> Copies the byte string pointed to by src to byte string, pointed to by dest.
>   **If the strings overlap, the behavior is undefined.** Also copies the terminating null-byte.

[`memmove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) can used to accomplish the task, remembering to copy the null terminator.

Comment: @MitchWheat, yes it is but I posted it as an answer not a comment. I also provided a possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

you can also write your own code to avoid the undefined behavior:

```
void delete_char(char *str, int i) {
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (; i < len - 1 ; i++)
    {
       str[i] = str[i+1];
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: No reason to call `strlen` in the for loop (quadratic complexity).

Comment: @MattEckert fixed that truble

Comment: It doesn't work, the last character is repeated. (Code also has a typo `srt`.) But there is no need to call `strlen` *at all* :) -- unless you need to validate `i` before running, you can do `if (str[i]) do str[i] = str[++i]; while (str[i]);`

Comment: @Jongware fixed the type, there are many ways to do it. literally thousands. that doesn't mean that it is a bad way or you shouldn't do strlen

Comment: Granted, but your code is *not* one of those 1,000s that work: it doesn't overwrite the last character, and so deleting index 1 in `test` results in `tstt`.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: What is compileonline? Using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc, it does not work. Your code one step at a time: `delete_char('test',1)=> len=4 so i=(1..2); str[1]=str[2];str[2]=str[3]; finally str[3+1]=0. Do you see the *logic* error?

Comment: wow, @Jongware was it that hard to say `str[i + 1] = '\0';` when `i = len - 1` causing the null terminator not to be where you want it to be? but i did worked, but because something else

Answer (score 2):

Accepting other answers `strcpy` cannot handle when strings got overlapped, in which [memmove](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) can be used as below,

`memmove(str+i, str+i+1, strlen(str) - i);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that loops through a string and adds the string[i] to a variable, but when it encounters the letter you want to remove, it just skips it, finally, it updates the string.

**Example:**

```
void remove_let(char str[], char letter) {
    int counter = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char rstr[len + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (str[i] != letter) {
            rstr[counter] = str[I];
            counter++;
        }

    rstr[counter] = '\0';
    strcpy(str, rstr);
}
```

*you can also specify how many times to remove a letter and then stop by passing the number of times as a parameter and just edit the logic by adding an if statement.*

Hope this helps!